# error on line 11 at column 16: xmlParseEntityRef: no name in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, xml, google-product-feeds

I am getting following issues when XML file open in the browser:-

> This page contains the following errors:
>
> error on line 11 at column 16: xmlParseEntityRef: no name
>
> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:** An XML parser returns the error "xmlParseEntityRef: noname"

**Cause:** There is a stray ‘&’ (ampersand character) somewhere in the XML text eg. some text & some more text

**Solution 1:**

> Remove the ampersand.

**Solution 2:**

```
Encode the ampersand (replace the ampersand '&' character with '&amp;',  '<' with '&lt;' and '>' with '&gt;' ) 
Remember to Decode when reading the XML text.
```

**Solution 3:**

```
Use CDATA sections (text inside a CDATA section will be ignored by the parser.) eg. <![CDATA[some text & some more text]]>
```